# Какие скрипты использовать в intellij idea чтобы удалить и создать базу данных PostgreSQL

Tags: java, база-данных, intellij-idea

Только обучаюсь, поэтому не пойму как правильно писать скрипты. Делаю всё через intelliji idea. Хочу удалить и затем заново создать базу данных в PostgreSQL, но выходит следующая ошибка:

```
РЅ D:\Java программы\sellmagazin Test_Sweater_begin> drop databases;
drop : Имя "drop" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или 
выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и 
правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
 + drop databases;
 + ~~~~
 + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound (drop:String)],CommandNotFoundException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Команды SQL нужно запускать через консоль SQL, а не в powershell или cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с SQL для Вас у меня есть два варианта:
Первый, Вам требуется установить плагин для работы в IDE. [Инструкция по настройке в IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/postgresql.html). Или же использовать Inteliji как командную строку, описано ниже.
Второй, использовать [другие](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/tutorial-accessdb) методы подключения к серверу PostgreSQL (я рекомендую этот вариант)

Ваша ошибка заключается в том, что Intelliji Idea из коробки не знает таких команд из коробки. Убедитесь в том, что Вы уже установили и настроили сервер, а затем подключайтесь и используйте требуемые Вам команды на сервере.

Comment: Сейчас добавлю картинок. Вводил много команд и у меня ничего не работает

Comment: Выкладывать ошибки [скриншотом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375) не стоит. Команды что Вы используете в скриншотах - они относятся к системе linux. Советую [почитать](https://1cloud.ru/help/windows/ustanovka-postgresql-na-windows-server) про установку и работу серверов на базе PostgreSQL и подобных. Если возникнут вопросы, обращайтесь!